# calloc and non contiguous memory blocks and void pointer

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation, dma, calloc

calloc function used to reserve memory and gives starting address of memory block but it is said that it may not allocate  in contiguous address space and rather it my allocate different different non contiguous blocks but starting address we get as return value of calloc will only   point to contiguous memory from starting address then if memory is allocated with two memory block then how pointer will jump to other memory block when one contiguous block will be occupied

```
void * calloc (size_t n, size_t size)
```

Comment: Are you talking about virtual or physical memory? If you allocate > page size of memory, the physical memory might not be contigous.

Comment: Punctuation wasn't invented for nothing. And where did you hear that `calloc` doesn't allocate contigous memory?

Comment: I think this is 'how does virtual memory work?'.

Answer (score 2):

> but it is said that it may not allocate in contiguous address space

Where is this "said" and what's the context?

`calloc()` returns a pointer to a contiguous block (in virtual address space) of size `nelem * size`.

Consecutive calls to `calloc()` don't give you *adjacent* blocks (in general).

Comment: hey bro search in internet you will find that calloc gives non contiguous blocks of memory and it uses linked list for that and here i am talking about logical address only (calloc will assigned blocks of non contiguous logical address .

Comment: Go to the site given below and see your self  in side is is given that calloc  may or may not give contiguous locations .....                     http://r4r.co.in/answer/index.php?id=22&option=C%20SUB

Comment: here is one other where it is mentioned that may or may not continuous     http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/dynamic_memmory_allocation/calloc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that:

> it my allocate different different non contiguous blocks but starting address > we get
>   as return value of calloc will only point to contiguous memory from
>   starting address

The C library function `void *calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)` allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it. The difference in **`malloc`** and **`calloc`** is that `malloc` does not set the memory to zero where as `calloc` sets allocated memory to zero.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc